# Objective-C. Object's value set to nil. But NSTimer based method is still executing

Tags: objective-c

I've got a simple app where class **Person** has a property **doggo** of type **Dog**.

object **doggo** is incrementing its **hungerLevel** property from the moment when **doggo** has a value (called with KVO from some ViewController).

```
-(void)dogGetsHungry {
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
      self.hungerLevel += 10;
      NSLog(@"Hunger level grows");
   }];
}
```

Now, some ViewController is observing the **doggo**'s **hungerLevel**. When **hungerLevel** exceeds, let's say, 160, **doggo** escapes (`self.person.doggo = nil;`).

But the **NSTimer** will never stop. It will execute forever. I thought it may have something to do with the retain cycle, so I set the **person**'s property **doggo** to be weak, but I am getting this warning

> Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment

I thought this a good use case, where the property of type **Dog** should be weak, to avoid **strong retain cycles**. If anyone could help me understand that too, I would be grateful.

Many thanks for the help.

Sidenote: I am using KVO, so I can learn about it better.

Comment: The use of `self` in the timer block causes the timer to maintain a strong reference to `doggo`. If you make this weak the timer may crash though because now it will call a released object.  The cleaner way: keep a reference to the timer, and when doggo escapes call an escape method on doggo in which you invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the NSTimer will never stop. I thought it may have something to do with the retain cycle

A scheduled timer is retained by the runloop. See [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/):

> Run loops maintain strong references to their timers, so you don’t have to maintain your own strong reference to a timer after you have added it to a run loop.

> Once scheduled on a run loop, the timer fires at the specified interval until it is invalidated. A nonrepeating timer invalidates itself immediately after it fires. However, for a repeating timer, you must invalidate the timer object yourself by calling its invalidate method.

You do need a reference to the timer to call `invalidate`, store the timer returned from `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` in a property.